# Why can't I edit my own contact info in Global Address List of Outlook client anymore?

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2016, outlook, exchange-server

Why can't I edit my own contact info in Global Address List of Outlook client?

The environment is on-premise exchange server 2016, in the ECP/Exchange Admin Center I already have user accounts set up with

Our outlook client version is the latest Microsoft Office 365,

In the past at other places I was able to within the GAL field itself on the client version of Outlook to directly edit my own self contact info, etc (and so did every other user) without having to go to the OWA or use a browser and without having to use RSAT/ADUC tools etc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOvCb.jpg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNYHY.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to edit the **mail contact** information, not an **Outlook contact**. So
you need to firstly right click on the contact name in the All Contacts list, then click Add to contacts and you will find the contact in the **Contacts** list, then double click the contact name to edit it.